# Django Annotate Conditional

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements, annotate

I want a list of users with a total sum of the charges that they each have. I only want to include charges in the sum that are due. This is returning a sum of all charges, it's not filtering out the charges that are not due yet.

```
user_array = User.objects.all().annotate(
   total_sum=Sum('charge__amount', only=Q(charge__due_date__lte=date))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
user_array = User.objects.filter(charge__due_date__lte=date).annotate(amount_due=Sum('charge__amount'))
```

motivated by https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses. The docs claim only the filtered relation values would be annotated.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I was completely stuck on that query.